# Overload sqrt function for string parameter

Tags: c++, overloading

I am looking to overload the sqrt function as follows, so that it can take in a string as an argument and return a string.

```
std::string sqrt(std::string b){
//do something
}
```

Is this allowed in C++ ? If so, is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine, provided your function interprets the string appropriately. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

std::string sqrt(std::string b)
{
    return std::to_string(std::sqrt(std::stoi(b)));
}

int main()
{
    std::string input = "625";
    std::string output = sqrt(input);
    std::cout << output;
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45a0d47348ba65f5)

The syntax is correct, but you may want to pass the string by `const` reference so you don't create a copy in case your string is a lvalue (for rvalues, a move will take place if using C++11).

Comment: But what it, for example, I am looking to do something completely unrelated to a square root and just call the function sqrt ? I.e., take in a string and return the string reversed.

Comment: @potatosoup You can do whatever you want inside the function. The example above transforms the string into an integer, and takes its square root. Of course you can do something else, but calling the function `sqrt` won't make too much sense and will confuse the others who may read your code.

Comment: The function should handle the case of parameters "banana" and "carrot".  Neither one is square, but at least the carrot is a root.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `std::stoi()` will throw up in that case :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the string represents a `double`, then you could use:

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

std::string sqrt(const std::string& b)
{
    return std::to_string(std::sqrt(std::stod(b)));
}
```

Similarly if you know the string represents an `int` use `std::stoi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
                          
                using namespace std;
                typedef unsigned char uchar;
                typedef unsigned short ushort;
                  
                #define MAX_LEN 3100
                #define bigint ushort *
                #define base 10
                  
                bigint tmp = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                bigint prr = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                bigint tmp1 = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                bigint tmp2 = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                  
                int cmp(bigint a, bigint b){
                    if(a[0]!=b[0]) return (int)a[0]-b[0];
                    for(register int i=a[0];i>0;i--)
                        if(a[i]!=b[i]) return (int)a[i]-b[i];
                    return 0;
                }
                  
                bigint read(){
                    bigint r = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                    char s[MAX_LEN];
                    scanf("%s",s);
                    int c = 0, l = strlen(s);
                    if(l>1)
                        for(int i=0;i=c; i--)
                        r[l-i]=s[i]-'0';
                    return r;
                }
                  
                void write(bigint n){
                    for(int i=n[0];i>0;i--)
                        printf("%d",n[i]);
                }
                  
                void smul(bigint a, ushort b, bigint c) {
                    long i, temp;
                    ushort carry=0; 
                    for (i=1; i0 && c[c[0]]==0) c[0]--;
                }
                  
                void shift(bigint a, int s){
                    for(int i=a[0];i>0;i--)
                        a[i+s] = a[i];
                    for(int i=1;i= base) {
                            c[i] = temp - base;
                            carry = 1;
                        } else {
                            c[i] = temp;
                            carry = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    for (; i = base) {
                            c[i] = temp - base;
                            carry = 1;
                        } else {
                            c[i] = temp;
                            carry = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (carry) {
                        c[i] = carry;
                        c[0] = a[0]+1;
                    } 
                    else c[0] = a[0];
                    while(c[0]>0 && c[c[0]]==0) c[0]--;
                }
                  
                ushort findBin(bigint a, bigint r, int cur){
                    // though... it's not a binary search.
                    short res = base-1;
                    ushort up = base-1, down = 0;
                    while(res>0){
                        smul(r, 2, tmp1);
                        smul(tmp1, res, tmp2);
                        shift(tmp2, cur-1);
                        summ(prr, tmp2, tmp);
                        tmp1[0]=1; tmp1[1]=res;
                        smul(tmp1, res, tmp2);
                        shift(tmp2, cur*2-2);
                        summ(tmp, tmp2, tmp1);
                        if(cmp(tmp1,a)=base) res--;
                    smul(r, 2, tmp1);
                    smul(tmp1, res, tmp2);
                    shift(tmp2, cur-1);
                    summ(prr, tmp2, tmp);
                    tmp1[0]=1; tmp1[1]=res;
                    smul(tmp1, res, tmp2);
                    shift(tmp2, cur*2-2);
                    summ(tmp, tmp2, prr); 
                    return r[cur]=res;
                }
                  
                bigint sqrt(bigint a){
                    bigint r = new ushort[MAX_LEN];
                    r[0] = (a[0]+1)>>1;
                    for(register int i=1;i>1;
                        r[cur]=findBin(a, r, cur);
                        cur--;
                    }
                    return r;
                }
                  
                // Program entry
                int main(int argc, char** argv) {
                    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
                    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
                    bigint n; bigint s;
                    prr[0]=0;
                    n = read();
                    s = sqrt(n);
                    write(s);
                    return 0;
                }
```